# The window does not close in 10 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to finish the animation when 10 seconds have passed. To do so, I added the timer to the animation `start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()` and check this timer inside the `for` loop `seconds > max_simulation_time`.

However, the window does not close in 10 seconds. It only closes when I move the mouse on the screen. A bit weird behaviour.  What am I doing wrong?
I run the code in Jupyter notebook if it may be an important detail.

```
class Environment():

    def __init__(self, title):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)

        # ...


    def run(self):   
        carryOn = True
        max_simulation_time = 10
        start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        while carryOn:
            seconds=(pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (seconds > max_simulation_time):
                    carryOn = False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            agent_action = 1
            self.all_sprites.update(self.screen, agent_action)
            self.screen.fill((0, 40, 0))
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = Environment("TEST")
    env.run()
```

Also, is there any way to just `break` the animation when 10 seconds have passed and start everything from the beginning (make reset), **without closing the window**?

**UPDATE:**

If I do it this way:

```
class Environment():

    def __init__(self, title):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)

        # ...


    def run(self):   
        carryOn = True
        max_simulation_time = 10
        start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        while carryOn:
            seconds=(pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000
            if (seconds > max_simulation_time):
                carryOn = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    carryOn = False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = Environment("TEST")
    for epochs in range(1,3):
        env.run()
```

<...> then I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
error                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-102fa6124bbf> in <module>()
    515     #env.run()
    516     for epochs in range(1,3):
--> 517         env.run()

<ipython-input-1-102fa6124bbf> in run(self)
    471                 pygame.quit()
    472                 quit()
--> 473             for event in pygame.event.get():
    474                 if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
    475                     carry_on = False

error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restart the simulation you can just create a new instance of `Environment` and call its `run` method. The `error: video system not initialized` occurs because you continue using pygame functions after you called `pygame.quit()` (which uninitializes all modules). You have to call `pygame.init()` again to prevent that.

Calling `pygame.display.quit()`, `pygame.quit()` and `quit()` is actually unnecessary (except for people who use IDLE and maybe other tkinter based IDEs) and you can just let Python close the game as any other program after finishing the while loop.

```
class Environment:

    def __init__(self, title):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)
        # ...

    def run(self):
        carryOn = True
        max_simulation_time = 10
        start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        while carryOn:
            seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks) / 1000
            if seconds > max_simulation_time:
                carryOn = False
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    carryOn = False

        # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for epochs in range(1,3):
        Environment("TEST").run()
```

If you don't want to create new instances, you could also give the `Environment` class a `reset` method in which you just reset all relevant attributes, and then call it when the simulation time is up.

Answer (score 3):

I think it probably has something to do with checking if you've exceeded your `max_simulation_time` only within your `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop.

That's why it only happens when you move the mouse. Check if you've exceeded that time before branching into that for loop.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I moved `if (seconds > max_simulation_time):` outside of for loop and now it works. But can you please answer the second part of my question?

Comment: As for the second part: just don't call neither  `pygame.display.quit()` `pygame.quit()` and `quit`. Instead you could fill the screen with a background color calling, and put a  `break` statement there: it will exit from the while loop, and from the `run` function - jsut add the logic outside teh `run` function to call it again with new parameters for the next animation.